# Как временно хранить записи в таблицах?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, база-данных

Пользователь вносит запись в таблицу. Через несколько минут эта запись и все ссылки на неё должны удалиться.

Как такое организовать? Какую базу лучше использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Redis](http://redis.io/) — хранение в памяти, указываете срок жизни при сохранении нового ключа.

Comment: @sergiks, а если часть данных я хочу хранить постоянно. Redis подходит?

Comment: Да, он умеет на диск сбрасывать и считывать потом — см. [Redis persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

Comment: @sergiks, например, пользователь регистрируется на сайте, и нужно постоянно хранить данные. Конечно, как вы написали, можно сбросить на диск, но есть ли в этом смысл? То есть может лучше совместить две базы (redis и mysql)? Или нет в этом особого преимущества?

Comment: На вашем сервере ограниченный ресурс - оперативка. Ее нужно побольше и для Redis и для mysqld. Поэтому лучше что-то одно выбрать. Redis это не БД, а хранилище ключ-значение.

Временные даные можно хранить и в MySQL: к записям добавлять поле DateTime или timestamp, означающее, когда они были созданы, и стирать просроченные задачей по cron'у, или [событиями](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) в самом MySQL 5.6+